Efficient Methods for Creating Moving Frontline Animation in Unity
What is a better way to create moving frontline animation in Unity?
Hi, I'm new in the Unity and I'm interested to create a moving frontline map animation for a strategy game.
Here is what I want to do with animation.

Red: Frontline, Green: My Territory, Blue: Enemy Territory
My idea is use "Polygon" and "vertex" to create this animation.
For example, Polygon1 (with multiple vertex) describe "My Territory" and trough animation.

Purple dot: vertex
I can move the position of vertex in each milisec to generate a moving frontline.
Is this a good idea? Or is there any other better option?
I saw a comment that suggest to use "Voronoi Diagram" but which one sounds better?

Keep in mind that a mesh has to have faces to be visible, and in Unity the faces must be triangles. "use voronoi diagram" is too vague. It's possible that they meant to use a voronoi diagram algorithm to generate the triangles that make up the mesh.

Hi Kevin, thanks for comment.
I guess I should use vertex shader to change the form of polygon as animation(morphing: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/167684/morphing-a-3d-model-into-a-sphere-or-cube-using-a-vertex-shader).
Could the morphing from "form1" -> "form2" -> "form3" ->... "form n" be difficult?
Or is there other better option?
